# UITableViewController- showing only rows with content and an image where there is none

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-experience

When creating a `UITableViewController` there are two situations that create an "ugly" UX

1. calling/open it without any data in it --> shows an empty table (i.e. empty rows,`UITableViewCell`,  as many as fit in the window)
2. calling/open it with fewer rows of content that fit the window --> show the full rows followed by empty rows

[image]

I wish to receive the following result:

1. if there is no data show a picture or view with text - there isn't any data yet or something like that
2. show only the full lines and no more rows (blank or background image)

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second UX case? I'm a little confused what you mean.

Comment: @CraigOtis if each cell is has a height of 50, then lets say in a screen there can be 10 rows. Now say the data source is an array with 2 objects that means the uitableviewcontroller will present 2 rows with the data of the 2 objects and 8 empty lines like in the first scenario, my wish is to see these two lines of data but instead of 8 empty lines either 1 empty line with height of the remaining 8 or better yet to see a background image of the table not the cells, please let me know if now it makes more since.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little confused. Your datasource should specify how many rows are being shown - why would you have 8 empty lines? Can you maybe post a screenshot?

Comment: @CraigOtis added the image for your request

Comment: Ah, I see. If you're using `UITableViewCell`, you might as well just leave them - it's the OS standard, and removing them manually deviates a bit from how other standard iOS apps look. But, you can also look at the `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, which will only show as many rows as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

To add these effects, you will probably have to make your own UITableViewController from a regular UIViewController, and even subclass UITableView. If you have a regular UIViewController with your filler image/text as the background, you can place a UITableView on top and hook up the delegate/datasource. Now, in your code, detect when there is no data available and set the hidden property of the UITableView accordingly.
As for the following empty rows, you will either have to turn off the row separators (in IB), or subclass a UITableView (can't help you there). Good luck!